# Espresso non launcher activity test

Tags: android, android-espresso

Is is possible to test a non launcher activity in isolation using espresso? If not then how do you propose testing UI for all the activities of an app?

I am using ActivityTestRule to start the activity being tested but my activity gets destroyed immediately after it is created.

Comment: Sorry but I think you're wrong. ActivityTestRule can handle non-launcher activity.

Comment: @olivejp When I do that my activity gets created but gets destroyed immediately. What am I doing wrong? Any Ideas?

Comment: Share your test code !

Comment: @olivejp figured it out It was just that the activity had a parent activity with some checks for security which destroyed the activity as soon as it was created!! Thanks for replying though